# Call Meteor.call() and wait inside `before: insert` hook

Tags: javascript, meteor, ecmascript-6, synchronous, meteor-autoform

**Scenario:**

I am trying to insert an `Appointment` for a client using `autoform` only when the dates do not clash. below is the code to get brief Idea.

```
{{#autoForm id='insertAppointmentForm' collection=appointment type="insert" 
              doc=this validation="browser"}}
    <fieldset>
      <!-- All fields here -->
    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit" class="btnn"> Create </button>
{{/autoForm}}
```

I am adding hook to above autoform `insert` code as below,

```
var hooksObject = {
  before: {
    insert: function(doc) {
      console.log(doc);
      Meteor.call('checkAppointmentClash', doc, function(error, response){
          if(error){ } else { }
      });
      return doc; // I want to wait here 
    }
  },
  onSuccess: function(formType, result) {},
  onError: function(formType, error) {}
};

AutoForm.addHooks(['insertAppointmentForm'], hooksObject, true);
```

**Problem:**

The issue here is that form gets submitted even if `error` returned from `Meteor.call()` and inserts the `document` to database. I know that the `Meteor.call()` is asynchronous call, but how can I wait for the result? only then I want to proceed with submit if no error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hooks can work asynchronously. From the [documentation](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#callbackshooks):

> These functions can perform asynchronous tasks if necessary. If asynchronicity is not needed, simply return the document or modifier, or return `false` to cancel submission. If you don't return anything, then you must call `this.result()` eventually and pass it either the document or modifier, or `false` to cancel submission.

So the code could look like this:

```js
insert: function(doc) {
  // note using () => {} to bind `this` context
  Meteor.call('checkAppointmentClash', doc, (error, response) => {
    if(error) {
      this.result(false);
    } else {
      this.result(doc);
    }
  });
  // return nothing
}
```

Although, I'd suggest you to rethink your flow. It's wrong to check for "clash" in a hook. You should be doing that on "user entered data" step and disable/enable "Submit" button accordingly.

Comment: checking clash on "user entered data" is not at a feasible solution in terms of performance(even if I use `_.debounce` to control requests). Checking it on hook makes just one call to server and it fits my application needs.

Comment: @AnkurSoni I didn't mean "check continuously", just once, when user has already enter data in the field. Of course, that would be meaningless, if you need _all_ fields to check for the clash :)